# Maximisation subject to an integer constraint

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, discrete-optimization

I am trying to solve an unconstrained maximisation problem. The objective function is quadratic in the (single) choice variable. Annoyingly, the choice variable must be an integer. Is there some general theorem that tells me that the solution to this problem is approximately the same (within $\pm 1$) as the solution to the simpler problem obtained by ignoring the integer constraint?

To provide the details, my problem is
\begin{equation}
\max_{b \in \mathbb{X}} (v - b)\left(1 - p + \frac{pb}{x+1}\right)^{n-1}.
\end{equation}
where $\mathbb{X} = \{0, 1, ..., x$} for some $x \in \mathbb{N}$, $p \in [0, 1]$, $v \in \mathbb{X}$ and $n \geq 2$. If I simplify the problem by pretending that I could choose any $b\in [0, x]$, not just integer $b$, I obtain the 'solution’:
\begin{equation}
b^* = \max\left\{\left( \frac{n - 1}{n} \right)v - \left(\frac{1 - p}{p}\right)\frac{x}{n}, \hspace{0.3em}0\right\}
\end{equation}
Since my objective function is quadratic in the choice variable $b$, and so single peaked around $b^*$, it seems 'obvious' that the actual solution must be close (within $\pm 1$) to the 'pretend' solution $b^*$. I guess there must be a general theorem which assures this?

Many thanks in advance for any ideas or pointers!

Comment: How did you obtain $b^*$? It doesn't look correct to me.

Comment: So I differentiated with respect to $b$ and set the derivative equal to zero. This then yields the non-zero solution (i.e. the first argument of the max function). A little heuristically, I then claim that $b^* = 0$ when the solution obtained from the first order condition yields a negative solution. (I admit that I did not bother with Kuhn-Tucker etc.)

Comment: Why does the solution look wrong to you?

Comment: It looked wrong before you edited the question: it was not $v-b$ but just $v$, so when taking the derivative there's some $n-2$ exponent and thus $b^*$ must contain some $\log$. Now it looks "more" correct, though the final solution is still not correct: What if the expression in the $max$ is larger than $x$? The solution should looks like this: $b^* = \min(x, \max(B, 0))$ where $B$ is the solution of the derivative.

Comment: Anyway, I'll help you out in a few minutes (I'm currently busy typing an answer to another question).

Comment: Thanks! I look forward to reading your answer. As I mention in the question, I think the key is that my objective function is single peaked (but am unaware of any existing theorems that make use of this idea).

Comment: Also 1) apologies for the typo, it should indeed be $v - b$ not just $v$ as I have now written 2) the expression in the max can never be larger than $x$ (note that $v \leq x$)

Comment: Sorry I'll be back in about an hour. A hint so maybe you can do it yourself: notice that the function is increasing on $(-\infty, B]$ and decreasing on $[B, +\ infty)$.

Comment: Haha thanks! I have indeed managed to now figure this out (using single-peakedness)

Comment: Great! Be careful because the optimum might not be the closest to $B$. You should take the closest on the left and the closest on the right, and compare them.

Comment: For maximization of a concave function, an integer-valued maximizer arises from rounding the continuous maximizer up or down.  Same story for convex minimization.

Comment: @RobPratt Yes that is clear to me, however can you provide a reference? For the paper I am writing I would prefer to cite something than to either write a proof or just write 'it is obvious'...